# Passing arrays to variable length argument lists

Tags: c#, arrays, parameters

If I have a function

```
void Foo(params int[] bar){}
```

The following runs fine:

```
int[] a1 = {1, 2, 3};
int[] a2 = {4, 5, 6};
Foo(1, 2, 3);
Foo(a1);
```

But these give compile errors:

```
Foo(a1, 1, 2, 3);
Foo(1, 2, a1);
Foo(1, a1, 2);
Foo(a1, a2, 1, 2, 3);
```

because only the first argument is allowed to be an int[], the rest have to be ints.

The final example is what I would like to do, but the language won't let me without combining the arrays first. I really like the simplicity of the syntax, and I would rather not add to the code more than I have to. Does anyone have a nice way to do this?

Comment: What made you think `Foo(a1, 1, 2, 3);` where `a1` is an `int[]` should work? Have you tested it? On which version of the compiler?

Comment: Are you sure `Foo(a1, 1, 2, 3)` works and it calls the same overload as `Foo(1,2,3)`? I tested on .net 3.5 SP1 and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Fair enough. Visual studio let me type it without warning, but not the others. They all fail on compile. I'll edit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's weird. `Foo(a1, 2, 3)` shouldn't work. You should either pass an array or a bunch of integers. You can't mix them AFAIK. Do you have another overload or something?

There's not really a neat syntax for doing that. The most concise one I can think of is:

```
Foo(a1.Concat(a2).Concat(new[] {1,2,3}).ToArray());
```

Comment: I agree `Foo(a1, 2, 3)` cannot work without another overload.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed, its very odd `Foo(a1, 2, 3)` works.

Heres an extension method for .Concat to make Mehrdad's syntax a little easier on the eyes.

```
public T[] Concat<T>(this T[] first, params T[] other)
    {
        T[] output = new T[first.Length+other.Length];

        first.CopyTo(output,0);
        other.CopyTo(output,first.Length);
        return output;
    }
```

Can be used as follows:

```
Foo(a1.Concat(a2).Concat(1,2,3));
```

Comment: Note that `Enumerable.Concat` is evaluated lazily while yours does the copy on each call. It can be inefficient if the number of `Concat` calls grows.